# How do I convert this Access Query to mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

This question is continuation of the following question:
[How do I convert this Access Query to mySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20661805/7134679)

I want to represent the above in my code as follows:

the Access SQL FROM statement is as below

```
FROM qryvw_employees 
INNER JOIN ((Tbl_Clients INNER JOIN (Tbl_Assignments 
INNER JOIN Tbl_Tasks ON Tbl_Assignments.Assignment_ID = Tbl_Tasks.Assignment_ID) ON Tbl_Clients.PAN = Tbl_Assignments.PAN) 
INNER JOIN qryvw_subtasks ON Tbl_Tasks.TaskID = qryvw_subtasks.TaskID) ON qryvw_employees.ID = Tbl_Tasks.Assigned_To
```

Based on the reply in this query I am trying this:

```
FROM 
qryvw_employees
INNER JOIN (tbl_clients 
INNER JOIN tbl_assignments ON tbl_clients.`PAN` = tbl_assignments.`PAN`
INNER JOIN tbl_tasks ON tbl_assignments.`Assignment_ID` = tbl_tasks.`Assignment_ID`
INNER JOIN qryvw_subtasks ON tbl_tasks.`TaskID` = qryvw_subtasks.`TaskID`) ON qryvw_employees.`ID` = tbl_tasks.`Assigned_To`
```

The diagram of the above relationship that I am trying to achieve is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMOek.png)

plz assist, do not delete on the basis of low reputation.  this is genuinely proper doubt since two tables have a one to many relationship and this is not covered in the above question.

My question is how do i represent the two one to many relationship (as shown in diagram) in the SQL statement.  This is continuation to the  How do I convert this Access Query to mySQL query? link above.

Comment: now what is the question ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query works in MySQL when the statement is as generated by Access iteself.  No change required. Here is the answer below:

```
FROM 
qryvw_employees
INNER JOIN (tbl_clients 
INNER JOIN tbl_assignments ON tbl_clients.`PAN` = tbl_assignments.`PAN`
INNER JOIN tbl_tasks ON tbl_assignments.`Assignment_ID` = tbl_tasks.`Assignment_ID`
INNER JOIN qryvw_subtasks ON tbl_tasks.`TaskID` = qryvw_subtasks.`TaskID`) ON qryvw_employees.`ID` = tbl_tasks.`Assigned_To`
```

Answer (score 0):

do the fact you are just using INNER query you should not use  ()  and nested  subquery  ..

```
  select your_col1, your_col2, ..., your_colN

  FROM qryvw_employees 
  INNER JOIN Tbl_Assignments 
  INNER JOIN Tbl_Tasks ON Tbl_Assignments.Assignment_ID = Tbl_Tasks.Assignment_ID
  INNER JOIN Tbl_Clients ON Tbl_Clients.PAN = Tbl_Assignments.PAN
  INNER JOIN qryvw_subtasks ON Tbl_Tasks.TaskID = qryvw_subtasks.TaskID
  INNER JOIN  ON qryvw_employees.ID = Tbl_Tasks.Assigned_To
```

*anyway  in mysql each nested subquery should be named with proper alias  eg: 
    select from ( select  .... from my_table) t1_alias*

Answer (score 0):

I think your from clause will be like below

```
     FROM qryvw_employees INNER JOIN 
     ((Tbl_Clients INNER JOIN 
  (Tbl_Assignments INNER JOIN Tbl_Tasks 
  ON Tbl_Assignments.Assignment_ID = Tbl_Tasks.Assignment_ID)
   ON Tbl_Clients.PAN = Tbl_Assignments.PAN) 
  INNER JOIN qryvw_subtasks ON Tbl_Tasks.TaskID = qryvw_subtasks.TaskID)
  ON qryvw_employees.ID = Tbl_Tasks.Assigned_To
```

Comment: It seems that in MySQL server if I put the same code (as made by MS Access with the brackets) it works!

    FROM qryvw_employees 
    INNER JOIN ((Tbl_Clients INNER JOIN (Tbl_Assignments 
    INNER JOIN Tbl_Tasks ON Tbl_Assignments.Assignment_ID = Tbl_Tasks.Assignment_ID) ON Tbl_Clients.PAN = Tbl_Assignments.PAN) 
    INNER JOIN qryvw_subtasks ON Tbl_Tasks.TaskID = qryvw_subtasks.TaskID) ON qryvw_employees.ID = Tbl_Tasks.Assigned_To

Comment: @ zaynul abadin tuhin, do add the above as an answer. i can't, given my points

Answer (score 0):

The `FROM` clause results in a list of subtasks multiplied with all clients that are related to the subtasks' assignments.

You can start with whichever table, it's up to you. Let's keep this the employee table. Then join the next table. The table related to the employees is the task table. Take this and join it on the employee ID. The next table to join can either be the subtasks table or the assignements table. Choose whichever. And so on, always add the next table to what you already have.

```
from qryvw_employees e
join tbl_tasks t on t.assigned_to = e.id
join qryvw_subtasks st on st.taskid = t.taskid
join tbl_assignments a on a.assignment_id = t.assignment_id
join tbl_clients c on c.pan = a.pan
```

If you don't select columns from all tables in your `SELECT` clause or if there is some aggregation in the query  (`SUM`, `COUNT`, ..., `GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT` maybe?), then you may want to join derived tables (subqueries) or move tables to the `WHERE` clause for readability and/or performance. Without seeing what you are actually selecting, this is all advice I can give.